# Documentation on SharePoint 2016 Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint-2016

I am writing an application that will need to insert files into a SharePoint 2016 document library from outside of Share Point. I have found that the Rest API should be capable of doing this, but I cannot find any good documentation that shows me the end points that are available and how to properly use it (yes I have seen the MSDN documentation, but haven't seen what I am looking for). Can anyone suggest a place where I can find this kind of documentation? The main things that I will need to do is to insert files from a byte array, read a file (be able to deliver the file back to my user), and possibly replace files.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Not sure if this question is allowed or not, just not finding what I need on Google, and it doesn't help that I don't know much about Share Point to start with.

Comment: `getfolderbyserverrelativeurl`. Not putting as answer because I don't know anything about SharePoint, but it does seem like this is a very googleable question.